# Noise budget stops decreasing further, while running simple additions

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I'm experimenting with Microsoft SEAL 3.4.5. I've a simple addition, which I run within a for-loop.

```
for( int i = 0; i < count; i = i + 1 ) {
    outfile << i + 1 << ",";
    evaluator.add_inplace(current_encrypted, add_encrypted);
    outfile << decryptor.invariant_noise_budget(current_encrypted) << ",";
    decryptor.decrypt(current_encrypted, decrypted_value);
    outfile << "0x" + decrypted_value.to_string() << endl;
}
```

Basically I'm adding up fives 10000 times. While doing this I return the noise budget after every calculation. Why the noise budget decreases quicker in the beginning?

I used the following parameters:

- poly_modulus_degree: 2048
- plain_modulus: 65536
- coefficient_modulus: 54

According to the source code of Microsoft SEAL the noise budget is defined as follows:
$ \text{noise_budget} \approx log_2(\frac{\text{coeff_modulus}}{\text{plain_modulus}})$

[image]

Comment: How is the noise budget defined?

Comment: I've added a definition of the noise budget. I don't know how the noise reduction is defined for each operation. Maybe this is the key to understand the result.

Comment: Looks like you are adding always the same value "add_encrypted" to "current_encrypted". At the beginning both are at the same noise level, so the budget goes down quickly. Later, relatively spoken, "add_encrypted" has much less noise than "current_encrypted", so the budget goes down slower. As in most calculations you want to add/multiply values with similar noise budget, the noise budget scale has to be logarithmic.